# insert control characters in nvarchar or varchar from SQL script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Given SQL Server 2012, how can I insert control characters (the ones coded under ASCII 32, like TAB, CR, LF) in a nvarchar or varchar column from a SQL script?

Comment: These all work fine inside a string literal too.

Comment: @MartinSmith can you elaborate on that? Is it related to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749961/difference-between-hex-constants-and-decimal-constants-in-sql-server ?

Comment: SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to like all those characters though. [So screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BFmTL.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I miss something in the question you can do this using [TSQL CHAR()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) function:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(ColName) VALUES(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
```

Will insert CR/LF. Same for other codes.

*Edit* there is [TSQL NCHAR()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx) as well for Unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks. Big duh feeling here, as I was already thinking about hex->varchar conversion. Simplest solutions are the best. +1 and accepted. (:

Comment: Please note that the function may vary depending on the type of your column, using the wrong function can result in wrong encoding.

nchar/nvarchar http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

char/varchar http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Added `NCHAR` to your answer (sorry @AgustinCoder, I only found out about your answer after my edit, will upvote you as well)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the function may vary depending on the type of your column, using the wrong function can result in wrong encoding.

nchar/nvarchar
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

char/varchar
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx